# How to know whether a new table was created with pandas to_sql?

Tags: pandas, sqlite, pandas-to-sql

I will be inserting new values into existing tables all the time, hence the if_exists will set to append.

On some occasions there will be no existing table and I want to preform some additional operation when this is the case.

How to I know if a new table was created when using the append approach?

Comment: Do you know the table name prior to inserting the new values? If so, check if the table exists prior to inserting.

Comment: thanks for the idea. I know the table name, but I actually have to create several such tables, so I would have to check for each one.